# xfs fails with errors on dmesg

Tags: linux, xfs

I have a strange error on a linux box with xfs, and I don't know how to debug and fix it.

Below is an excerpt from dmesg :

```
Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 34412208504
sd 7:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sde: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 35840057200
sd 7:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sde: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 35799212408
sd 7:0:0:0: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sde: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 39444095352
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 32974487928
device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 8:80.
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 32973734264
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 22213009752
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 32940065144
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 32974552944
sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
   <<vendor>> ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

Info fld=0x17
end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 17956282744
Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 9666270717
lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
I/O error in filesystem ("dm-3") meta-data dev dm-3 block 0xe7ffb01c2       ("xlog_iodone") error 5 buf count 12800
Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 4028959741
lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
xfs_force_shutdown(dm-3,0x2) called from line 956 of file fs/xfs/xfs_log.c.  Return address = 0xffffffff883bec58
Filesystem "dm-3": Log I/O Error Detected.  Shutting down filesystem: dm-3
Please umount the filesystem, and rectify the problem(s)
```

How I can debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: Holly ***. You have your block device malfunctioning "end_request: I/O error, dev sdf, sector 17956282744" and what are you gonna debug then? O_o

Comment: It's weird, I've rebooted the machine and now it has mounted the filesystem , exported it, mounted from another machine, and works fine. I don't understand anything. O_O!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is a very old post, but as the answer is incorrect, I think it can be useful to future visitors to post a correct answer...

The error message reported by the OP has nothing to do with XFS by itself, rather it is the result of a bad drive/cable. Examining the error entry:

> end_request: I/O error, dev sde, sector 39444095352

The system can not retrieve data located on `sde` at LBA address `39444095352`. This generally means a bad block on disk.

> sd 7:0:0:1: SCSI error: return code = 0x08000002
>   sdf: Current: sense key: Aborted Command
>     vendor ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23ASC=0xc0 ASCQ=0x23

The SCSI command was aborted due to timeout (caused by the bad block) and the disk returns a specific vendor code explaining the error in more detail.

Issuing a `smartctl --all` shows various internal disk counter. Attributes with **ID 5 (Reallocated_Sector_Ct), 197 (Current_Pending_Sector) and 198 (Offline_Uncorrectable)** are of special interest because they shows the disk blocks unreadable/remapped situation.

What can you do in this case? **The safest and strongly preferred** approach is to backup the entire readable content to another, safe disk (maybe using something resilient to disk error, as [`ddrescue`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html))

If this approach is not possible, than two possibilities remains:

1. reboot with a live distro and issue a `badblocks -n <dev>` ([here for man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/badblocks)): it will start a non-destructive read/write test which should trigger the on-disk bad block remapping procedure
2. manually overwrite the affected bad blocks issuing something similar to `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sde bs=512 count=1 seek=39444095352`

Note that the two approaches above (especially the second one) **will** cause data loss, as the affected, unreadable sector will be overwritten.

After the recovery/overwrite completed you should run a complete filesystem check, in this case issuing `xfs_repair /dev/sde`

Comment: Obviously I don't have this problem any more, but I really appreciate your community effort, and for that I would like to give you a big THANK YOU . Keep up with the good work. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **xfs_db** command to debug the **XFS** filesystem. Please, use the following syntax:

```
xfs_db [device with XFS installed]
```